# Is it possible to change the color of dash-lines in jstree

Tags: jstree

Im using jstree with a dark background, so I wonder how can I change the color of dash-lines(not sure if I call it correctly) between each node. Is it possible with CSS?

As I checked, it seems the dash-lines coming from 32px.png file.

BR
Nima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit the 32px.png file to change the dotted line color.  I did this for my dark-background web page and it looks much better.  I edited the png file with Photoshop Elements and used the "Enhance| Adjust Color| Replace Color" menu to change the black color to a lighter grey by moving the Lightness slider.  I also changed the interior color of the selected arrows.  Once done editing, save a copy of the original and then replace the file in your CSS themes folder where style.css is.

I can't attach my copy of 32px.png, but here's how to make the change in Photoshop Elements.  Other photo editors likely have the same functionality.

[Replace Color in Photoshop Elements – Instructions](https://www.teachucomp.com/replace-color-in-photoshop-elements-instructions/)